# Show that $M=\{x^{m-1} : x\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $m\geq 1$ and  $G$ a group such that $x^my^m=(xy)^m.$ Show that $M=\{x^{m-1} : x\in G\}$ is a subroup of $G$.
I prove that
$e \in M$ and if $z\in M$, then $z^{-1}\in M$, but  i can't prove if $z,\,t \in M$, then $z\,t \in M$ !

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z,t\in M$, then $z=x^{m-1}$ and $t=y^{m-1}$, so $$zt=x^{m-1}y^{m-1}=x^{-1}x^my^my^{-1}=x^{-1}(xy)^my^{-1}=y(xy)^{m-1}y^{-1}=(yx)^{m-1}\in M$$

Answer (score 2):

If $z,t\in M$, you wish to show that $zt$ is of the form $a^{m-1},a\in G$.

Note that since $z,t\in M$ then $z=x^{m-1},t=y^{m-1}$. Then:
$$zt=x^{m-1}y^{m-1}\Rightarrow xzty=x^my^m=(xy)^m$$
Now multiply by $x^{-1}$ from the left and $y^{-1}$ to the right and get:
$$zt=(yx)^{m-1}=a^{m-1}$$
Which is what you wanted to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: From $$x^my^m=(xy)^m$$ we get $$x^{m-1}y^{m-1}=\underbrace{(yx)(yx)\cdots(yx)}_{\text{$(m-1)$-times}}.\quad\text{(How?)}$$

Answer (score 1):

To show closure, let $t=x^{m-1},z=y^{m-1}$.  Then we have $xtzy=(xy)^m\implies tz=x^{-1}(xy)^my^{-1}=(yx)^{m-1}$.